# Hit API only when there is change - Live Score

Tags: php, api, websocket, file-get-contents

I'm using an API that provides the score of the game. To show the score in real-time, I'm hitting API after every 2-3 seconds to see if any changes happen in the score but I think this method isn't very efficient. It would exceed my API requests very quickly. Is there any other way to achieve this method (that hits API only when there is a change in the score)? or Is this something that isn't possible with PHP?

This is what I'm currently doing (just an example)

```
<?php

while(true){

$api_url = "here goes url that returns response in json";
$score_api = file_get_contents($api_url);
$score_array  = json_decode($score_api, true);

$score = $score_array['result']['score'];

sleep(2); // hit API again after 2 seconds

}



?>
```

Comment: Check online on  server sent events.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it? Thank you @nice_dev

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Implement socket programming for that

Comment: Socket? What is it? Not familiar with it! How would I know if any change happens without hitting the API @PriyankMotivaras

Comment: By socket programming, they mean something that keeps the connection open, so that the server can send an update without the client requesting it. If you're using an API that is per-request limited, then you probably won't be able to set this up, as it requires access that the API owner definitely won't want to give you for security reasons. Reframing you question: Are you sure your users need to know the score has updated within 2 seconds of it happening? (Are they constantly watching the screen?)

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to show up the cricket score in the real time. As you know, it’s cricket, so the score will keep changing